# Large amount of scrollable text in Ubuntu touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

Is there a way to make a label scrollable in ubuntu touch sdk.  If not what is another way to have a large amount of uneditable text that can scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [TextArea](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/qml-ubuntu-components0-textarea.html) to provide scrollable text and set the `readOnly` property to `true`.